# How to use HttpListener in Identifying the hostheader usage

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, http, iis

I a trying to find a hostheader is already under usage. So I start a HTTP listener with an url. I expected an exception, as the url having host header is already registered. The code is below. The URL abc:81 is already up and running, however the listener starts and stops without exception. can anyone help

```
 bool notUnderUse;  
 HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
 listener.Prefixes.Add("http://abc:81/") ;
  try
   {
        listener.Start();
        listener.Stop();
        notUnderUse =  true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
     {
         notUnderUse = false;
     }
```

Comment: It works as expected, if i provide IP address port number. I mean it throws already under use exception.. However not working fine with host header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I coded the below function with various references and it worked fine.

```
 public static bool IsHostHeaderUnderUse(string ipAddress,string port, string hostname)
    {
        bool alreadyUnderUse = false;

        var header = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", ipAddress, port, hostname);
        int? iisVersion = IISUtility.GetIISVersion();
        if (iisVersion.HasValue && iisVersion < 7)
        {
            DirectoryEntry iis = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/W3SVC");
            foreach (DirectoryEntry directoryEntry in iis.Children)
            {
                var bindings = directoryEntry.Properties["ServerBindings"];
                if (bindings.Contains(header))
                {
                    alreadyUnderUse = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var serverManager = new ServerManager();
            foreach (Site site in serverManager.Sites)
            {
                foreach (var binding in site.Bindings)
                {
                    if (binding.BindingInformation.Contains(header))
                    {
                        alreadyUnderUse = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (alreadyUnderUse) { break; }
            }
        }
        return alreadyUnderUse;
    }
```